# Is there anything like "Epcot World Showcase" in other parts of the world?

Tags: japan, disney

I recently looked up whether there are Epcots at other disneylands/worlds and nothing came up on the internet, but I am curious as to whether there are other facilities similar to Epcot where there are some countries on showcase. Particularly, I am curious about Japan, since I'm going there soon, but I would love to know about ones in other countries.

[Here is a link to the world showcase website](http://www.wdwinfo.com/wdwinfo/guides/epcot/ep-worldshowcase.htm)

Comment: This appears to be a request for a list of things of some particular kind. This kind of question [doesn't work well on Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Where does it as for a list at all? If anything it is a simple Yes/No question. "Is there something like the Epcot Centre in Japan?"

Comment: See Wikipedia's article on [World's Fairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_fair) for similar idea.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder No. The question is "Are there Epcot-like things anywhere in the world? P.S., I'm most interested in Japan." Sure, if the answer is no, then it's a super-short list. But, if the answer is "yes" then that's not an adequate answer and the only adequate answer would be a list of all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the link - but it wasn't working as it was formatted as code (with 4 spaces in front). Fixed it for you now.

Answer (score 3):

## Not in Disney Complexes.

The Tokyo Disney Complex (Land, Sea, Hotels, Resort) does not have an Epcot Centre. The Epcot Centre in Orlando was actually built concurrently with Tokyo Disneyland. Further, the Epcot Centre idea was originally abandoned on Walt Disney's death having actually been a plan for a self sufficient city. When Disney revisited the idea, they scaled it back to merely a theme-park-sized rather than a city-sized project.

Specifically in Japan (Tokyo), you may look for something like the [Miraikan](https://www.miraikan.jst.go.jp/en/) in Odaiba run by the National Museum of Emerging Science and Innovation, which showcases new and emerging technologies from Japanese companies and universities.

If you wish to experience foreign culture in a Theme Park format then [Shima Spain Mura](http://www.parque-net.com/foreign/english/) is where you get to experience Spanish Culture. It is between Kyoto and Nagoya (about 2hrs train ride from either) and has mascots and characters reminiscent of Disney characters.

Comment: Do you know about whether there are some facilities that are more like epcot from a cultural standpoint?

Comment: @MorellaAlmann What do you mean by cultural? And what facilities are you referring too?

Comment: Morella is referring to the World Showcase section of EPCOT, with exhibits/ride combos for various countries

Comment: I am referring to the "world showcase" of countries that one can "tour around". I suppose "cultural" isn't the right word. I mean more of the setup that the epcot world showcase has.  As for facility, I mean just the section of the themepark that had the different sections and places one could "tour" around.

Comment: It would have been nicer if you had linked to one of the so-called "Epcot world showcase" so other users who are not aware would be aware of what it is.

Comment: @MorellaAlmann As shirish said in the previous comment, a link to exactly what you wanted to compare to would have been nice (I have never been to the US let alone Disney, Florida). There aren't too many places in Tokyo where you will see a whole lot of foreign countries represented on a permanent basis, however there are quite a few events where you are able to experience other cultures. One (that I will add to the answer) is the Shima Spain Mura in between Kyoto and Nagoya.

Comment: @shirish Good point. I've added an informational link in the question.